# Coding for 10 submit buttons on one page

Tags: button, submit

I need some guidance on how to properly code a dynamic web page containing 10 questions each having its own submit button.  Here's a quick background and what I'm doing.

I'm creating a question/answer page in which a user answers questions and hits Submit.  Each question has a point value which gets added to the user's bank if answered correctly.

The questions are populated on the page through a database table containing three fields - QuestionNumber, Question, Points.  Each Question has a QuestionNumber assigned to it so I can easily and quickly ID the question and answer. This displays fine (here's the code):

```
<? 
$rt = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE Status='Open' ORDER BY 'Number' LIMIT 10");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rt)) {
$number=$row[0]; 
$category = $row[1];
$question=$row[2];
$points=$row[4];

?>
<form action="processor.php" method="post" class="qForm">
<div class="questionCell">
<div class="question"><? echo $question; ?></div>
<div class="answer">Answer: <input class="inputField" name="a0001" type="text"  size="40" maxlength="40" />
<input name="HHQuestion" value="Question: <? echo $number;  ?>" type="submit" /></div>
</div>
</form>
<? 
} 
?>
```

This form gets repeated 10 times on the page, and each has its own question and QuestionNumber.  Also, every submit button has the value assigned based on the questionNumber.  I did this so that the user (young kids) knows which question they're about to answer.  This all displays very nicely on the page.

The problem I'm having is with the POST file "processor.php", which has not been created yet. The way I envision it to work is that when someone submits their answer, the processor.php file will capture the quesiotnNumber (that's assigned to the button) and answer from the text field, then validate it again the database table.

I know that I should be using SWITCH / CASE (as opposed to IF ELSE) when using multiple buttons, which I'm fine with.  But how do I capture the QuestionNumber on the form into the processor.php file?

My ultimate goal for this project is to just populate the question table in the database, and let the webpage work dynamically.

Thanks in advance for any help and guidance.

R

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused about your wording, but am I understanding correctly in thinking that you wish to submit the answer to each question to the database although you have them all running on the same page?

If so, I'd recommend using an AJAX library to send the data back and get a quick response. There are a number out there, but jQuery is very simple to use (along with having a number of other features). Below is some psuedocode:

```
function submitAnswer(questionid)
{
    answer = document.getElementById("a000"+questionid);
    $.get("processor.php", {"answer": answer, "question": questionid}, function (data) {
        if (data.response == "200") {
            document.getElementById("response-"+questionid).innerHTML = "Thanks for answering";
        }
    });
}
```

Then you could call it with something like:

```
<input type = "submit" onclick = "submitAnswer('<?=$number?>'); void(0); return false;">
```

Please note this is all psuedo! Your mileage may vary! Shout out if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi Andrew, you are correct in your understanding.  I'm a little familiar with AJAX and do use it for a log on another site. I do have a quick question about your answer.  What should the processor.php file contain?  I don't need specific coding just a general direction, such as should it contain just the query to run my check using SWITCH / CASE, or should it have more?  Thanks.

Comment: Hi there. I'm very sorry for the delay - I've been away for the last week. I'd recommend just an if check to see if the "question" variable has been sent. Then validate all of the input and check it against the database as you need. One thing to note is you can ask for a JSON response in the request dataType (see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and then return the response from the PHP script with _json_encode()_ on an array.